# Como crear un dict en python para hacer un bulk insert con el ORM de pydal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ocupo crear un dict en python para poder hacer un insert masivo en mi base datos

ocupo similar a esto:

```
[{'nombre': 'Alejandro'}, {'nombre': 'Juan'}, {'nombre': 'Timoteo'}]
```

ocupo crear algo similar a esto para guardarlo en una variable la sentencia en pydal es esta:

```
db.person.bulk_insert([{'name': 'Alex'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Tim'}])
```

he estado intentando crear un dict igual a ese pero no lo logro

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu duda o problema. ¿No te funciona el código que has puesto para el `bulk_insert()`? ¿O no sabes cómo crear la lista de diccionarios? En este segundo caso ¿dónde tienes la información que quieres convertir en lista de diccionarios?

Comment: la pregunta seria como hacer la lista para el bulk insert ?

Comment: Ok, la lista puedes crearla con una _list comprehension_ por ejemplo, lo cual requiere iterar sobre algo. ¿Qué información tienes para meter en la lista? ¿En qué formato la tienes? Por ejemplo, podría tratarse de una lista de nombres como `["Alejandro", "Juan", "Timoteo"]`, o tal vez un fichero en el que cada línea sea un nombre de usuario. O tal vez lo tienes en un JSON, o un YAML... falta esta información

Comment: si correcto utilizo list comprehension [{'name': 'Alex'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Tim'}]  pero como formulo la parte que está dentro de la lista esta parte [{'name': 'Alex'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Tim'}

Comment: Si,correcto los nombre vienen de una lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los nombres te vienen en una lista tal como esta:

```
nombres = ["Alejandro", "Juan", "Timoteo"]
```

Lo siguiente creará una lista de diccionarios como la que necesitas:

```
data = [ { "name": nombre } for nombre in nombres ]
```

Que después usarías así:

```
db.person.bulk_insert(data)
```

Esa sintaxis de poner `[ expresion for v in lista ]` es lo que se llama una *list comprehension*. También puedes hacerlo por el método más clásico de iterar y añadir elementos a una lista inicialmente vacía, así:

```
data = []
for nombre in nombres:
    data.append({"name": nombre}]
```

Ambos métodos son equivalentes y puedes elegir el que más claro sea para tí.